# Limit scrolling speed on ListRow

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I was looking at Netflix app and their scrolling behaviour.I would like to do the same but don't know where to start. I know how to override `LayoutManager` for `RecyclerView`(though I don't to save that as last resort). Is there easier way to control scrolling speed using RowPresenter ?

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @VipulKumar I think I did I was messing with leanback back then.

Comment: Okay. Please let me know if you figured out how. I'm stuck and there is no help.

Comment: .. what does the scrolling in Netflix look like?

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the logic on your activity class, ovverride keys (OnKeyDown) on a way that will ignore the key event for 3-4 millis or sth.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean res = false;
        if (current - mLastKeyDownTime < 300) {
            res = true;
        } else {
            res = super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            mLastKeyDownTime = current;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Leanback supports setting scrolling speed for `BaseGridView` from [version 1.1.0-alpha03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/leanback#1.1.0-alpha03). You can set scrolling speed by using a method named `setSmoothScrollSpeedFactor` in all sub-classes of  `BaseGridView`.